# std::unique_ptr::reset checks for managed pointer nullity?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, unique-ptr, delete-operator

I've been reading about the C++11 smart pointers in order to use them on my sources, the documentation I've been reading is the one on cppreference.com; while reading about the `std::unique_ptr`, on the [`reset` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) there's a documentation that seems incorrect to me (emphasis mine):

> Replaces the managed object.
>
> - Given `current_ptr`, the pointer that was managed by `*this`, performs the following actions, in this order:
>
>   1. Saves a copy of the current pointer `old_ptr = current_ptr`.
>   2. Overwrites the current pointer with the argument `current_ptr = ptr`.
>   3. **If the old pointer was non-empty, deletes the previously managed object `if(old_ptr != nullptr) get_deleter()(old_ptr)`**.

In the C++ standard documentation, we can read the well known delete null pointer feature:

Extract from `n3690` standard **5.3.5 Delete** (emphasis mine):

> If the value of the operand of the *delete-expression* is not a null pointer value, then:
>
> — If the allocation call for the new-expression for the object to be deleted was not omitted, the *delete-expression* shall call a deallocation function. The value returned from the allocation call of the new-expression shall be passed as the first argument to the deallocation function.
>
> — **Otherwise, the *delete-expression* will not call a deallocation function**.

So, I'm wondering why cppreference says that the `unique_ptr::reset` function checks for the nullity of the managed pointer before it's deletion even while te standard says that no deallocation function would be called over a null pointer (that's why the cppreference documentation seems incorrect to me).

Is kind of obvious that I must be mistaken and there must be a reason to do things this way, but I'm unable to imagine what reason it could be. Any hints?

PS: Where in the standard is defined how the `std::unique_ptr` must be implemented or behave? In the **20.9.1 Class template `unique_ptr`** I cannot found anything about the *check-for-nullity* stuff.

Comment: `delete` isn't the only thing done to get rid of a pointer-like resource. You can have a custom deleter that `free`s or does other things which don't like null pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the check for non-null is required by the standard (C++11, `[unique.ptr.single.modifiers]§4`):

> ```
> void reset(pointer p = pointer()) noexcept;
> ```
>
> *4 Effects:* assigns `p` to the stored pointer, and then **if the old value of the stored pointer, `old_p`, was not equal to `nullptr`, calls `get_deleter()(old_p)`**. [ *Note:* The order of these operations is significant because the call to get_deleter() may destroy `*this`. *—end note* ]

(emphasis mine)

**Discussion:** An alternative way to standardise it would be to put the "burden" on the user of the class, i.e. require all deleters (the default one *and* any custom ones) to work fine when invoked on a null pointer.

However, I understand the idea was to enable functions like `free()` and even things like a hypothetical `unlock_mutex(Mutex*)` to work as deleters out-of-the-box, regardless of how/if they handle null pointers. So putting this check into the `unique_ptr` itself broadens the selection of deleters which can be used directly.

Comment: And what could be the reason to do that if deleting a null pointer have no effect?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster What if the deleter is not the default deleter, and does not work with a null pointer?

Comment: well, I wass assuming that if you create a custom deleter, that custom deleter **must** conform some conditions like *do not try to operate over a null pointer*, but obviously, that was my mistake (and I cannot found nothing about conditions/preconditios about the custom deleter, so that must be the reason :)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Yes, that would have been an alternate route for the standard to take. But I understand the idea was to enable functions like `free()` and even things like a hypothetical `unlock_mutex(Mutex*)` work as deleters out-of-the-box, so they decided to put the burden on the `unique_ptr` instead of its user.

Comment: good point in that last comment, would you mind to include this explanation into the answer for future readers? (even after that I already accepted the answer)

Comment: @angew We'd had a lively discussion about this point at C++ and Beyond this year.  Particularly about how the documentation about the destructor of unique_ptr has different phrasing about the nullptr case.  The destructor explicitly calls out the behaviour of the nullptr case, but reset only talks about the non-nullptr case.  (Well, at least in the C++14/N3797 draft).  Neither actually guarantees that `get_deleter()(old_p)` is _not_ called in the nullptr case.

Answer (score 2):

What if your deleter does not do a simple delete operation ? What if your unique_ptr has a custom deleter that does something else, would you like your deleter to be called with nullptr as a parameter ? :D

Comment: If I ever wanted to allow my custom deleter to be called with a null pointer: I will check the nullity into the deleter itself ;P but now I can assume that my custom deleter will not be called with `nullptr` (even if I wanted to, for some random and freaking reason)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Actually the `delete` operator checking for a null pointer is the weird guy in a language where you are not supposed to pay for something you don't use (why would i have to pay for an additional check if i never delete `nullptr` ?), but i guess for historical reasons and to mimic the behaviour of `free()` it was made to check for `nullptr` since enough coders seems to rely on this behaviour. The same custom deleter you use could also be used in another context where checking for `nullptr` doesn't make much sense, it would be sad to require a wrapper just for a null check :)